# Angular 2 - set class according to attribute value

Tags: angular, attributes

Let's say I have a few buttons to sort a list:

```
<a class="order-by" href="#" (click)="Sort('id')" [ngClass]="{active: sortBy==='id'}">Id</a>
<a class="order-by" href="#" (click)="Sort('name')" [ngClass]="{active: sortBy==='name'}">Name</a>
<a class="order-by" href="#" (click)="Sort('age')" [ngClass]="{active: sortBy==='age'}">Age</a>
```

I'm using the value of each button ('id', 'name' & 'age') twice - for the click event and to set the 'active' class.
I would like this value to be set in a single place - I thought of an attirbute. Something like that -

```
<a class="order-by" href="#" [attr.sorting-value]="id" (click)="Sort([attr.sorting-value])" [ngClass]="{active: sortBy===[attr.sorting-value]}">Id</a>
```

But it's not working.

Is it possible in any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'recommend you to render such repeating element via `*ngFor`, so your model will belongs to component.

```
<a class="order-by" href="#"
  *ngFor="let item of list" 
  (click)="Sort(item.name)" [ngClass]="{ 'active': isActive(item.name) }">
 {{item.description}}
</a>
```

**Code**

```
list = [
  {name: 'id', description: 'Id'},
  {name: 'name', description: 'Name'},
  {name: 'age', description: 'Age'},
];

isActive(name: string){
   return name === this.sortBy;
}
```